# Laravel Eloquent DB Migration

Tags: sql, database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-migrations

We want to count the duration between two different date fields on a database. Can anyone help convert this SQL query to a database migration in Laravel?

```
CREATE TABLE api_incident_duration 
(START DATETIME, END DATETIME, elapsed DECIMAL(5, 2) 
AS (ROUND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, START, END) / 60, 2)));
```

Perhaps:

```
$table->dateTime('startdatetimepicker')->nullable();
$table->dateTime('enddatetimepicker')->nullable();
$table->decimal('elapsed', 5, 2)
   ->virtualAs(ROUND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, startdatetimepicker, enddatetimepicker) / 60, 2));
```

Comment: This is not valid PHP code. Do you mean `->virtualAs('ROUND(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, startdatetimepicker, enddatetimepicker) / 60, 2)')`?

Comment: yes my friend, it worked ! thank you very much !

Comment: @tphil Just for information , virtualAs is migration column modifiers. To know more : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/migration-column-modifiers.